# h2 named database schema not found

Tags: scala, h2, slick, in-memory-database

when I create h2 memory database with a "name", I can't seem to use the name to refer to the table and keep getting "schema not found". Any idea?

````
val con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:mytest;MODE=MYSQL;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1")
    val stm = con.createStatement

    val sql: String =
      """
        |create table mytest.test_table1(ID INT PRIMARY KEY,NAME VARCHAR(500));
        |insert into mytest.test_table1 values (1,'A');""".stripMargin

    stm.execute(sql).result
    ```

Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "mytest" not found; SQL statement:

create table mytest.test_table1(ID INT PRIMARY KEY,NAME VARCHAR(500));
insert into mytest.test_table1 values (1,'A'); [90079-199]
````

Answer (score 1):

1. `;MODE=MYSQL;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE` is only suitable for H2 1.4.197 and older versions. For H2 1.4.198 Beta and newer versions you need to use `MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE` instead, otherwise all identifiers will be case sensitive, unlike in MySQL.
2. Database name is not related to the schema name in H2. By default, there is only `PUBLIC` schema for your tables. If you need a different schema, you need to create it first with standard `CREATE SCHEMA mytest;` command.

Please also note that H2 1.4.199 is an old unsupported version of H2 database.